# joosy dynamic render deleting widget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, joosy

I'm in the process of making a simple Todo List application based on Joosy after completing the blog tutorial.

I'm having trouble with a @renderDynamic (which I was able to get working in the blog) in my TaskWidget.

When I click submit on the dynamic partial, it successfully posts back and updates the resource but it removes the widget content. Any thoughts?

My repo is here:
https://github.com/awinograd/todo_list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this discussion [github.com/roundlake/joosy/issues/23](https://github.com/roundlake/joosy/issues/23)

In short, you may not wish to put widgets or forms under the dynamic rendering. Or rebind them manually in callback passed to @onRefresh.